# Line gestion csv bash

Tags: bash, csv, line

sorry if this issue has been covered before but I couldn't find the topic.

My csv.csv :

```
uid:titi      
20220310  
uid:toto  
20220410  
uid:tata  
20220805  
uid:tuti  
20220304
```

What I want is that my new csv look like this:

newcsv.csv

```
titi;20220310   
toto;20220410    
tata;20220805  
tuti;20220304
```

I tried with read but I don't manage to split the line by peer.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cat csv.csv | sed 's/uid://g' | awk '{key=$0; getline; print key ";" $0;}'  | tr -d ' '
```

The output as you prefer:

```
titi;20220310
toto;20220410
tata;20220805
tuti;20220304
```

Comment: awk is always amazing. You can even use 
`awk 'BEGIN{RS="uid:"; FS="\n"} {print $1, ";", $2;}' csv.csv` but it may produce an empty first record.